# Как добавить смешанный текст PyQt5?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Имеется окно QTextEdit, используемое для вывода информации, в котором хотелось бы иметь строки без выделения, и строки выделенные жирным шрифтом. Какие имеются способы это сделать?

Comment: вам нужно чтобы изначально при запуске приложения был текст разного шрифта?

Comment: нет, в процессе работы я вычисляю значения параметров, и мне нужно выделять жирным шрифтом те параметры, значения которых выше порогового

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTextEdit понимает разметку html, вы можете выделить нужные строки соответствующими тегами. Соответственно, формируете строку в html формате и далее `textEdit.setHtml(htmlString)`. Еще можно почитать про QTextDocument в справке. Ситуация та же - можно различными способами сформировать необходимые данные для вывода, например с помощью QTextCursor.

Answer (score 0):

[QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) поддерживает `rich`-текст через `HTML`, для этого достаточно вызвать [setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop).

Поддерживаемый набор возможностей `HTML`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication([])

te = Qt.QTextEdit()
te.setHtml("""
<b>Hello</b> <i>Qt!</i><br>
<font color="red"><b>Привет<b></font> <font size="20">мир!</font>
""")
te.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]